# htaccess settings for allowing image uploads

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, file-upload

```
ForceType application/octet-stream

< FilesMatch "(?i)\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
ForceType none
< /FilesMatch>

AuthName "Authorization required"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

The above are `.htaccess` settings of a directory in my site, it says that the directory will force any files except images to write in the directory. I am uploading images to this place and what changes in the `reg.exp` in the file will make that happen.

I tried to change a few values, but I have very little knowledge in this particular sector.

Comment: How about removing the filesMatch section?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the `ForceType`, but as far as the `regex` goes... `(gif|jpe?g|png)$` ...

The `$` at the end means the end so it won't match `image-png.txt`, but it would match `image-txt.png` since `png` is one of the options and in the second filename it is at the end.  The `()` in this case mean that all the values divided by the `|`'s are the possible values at the end of the filename which would be a match.  The `?` in the middle of the `jpe?g` means that the `e` is optional, so `jpeg` and `jpg` would both be matches.

Just to hazard a guess you could probably just drop the `ForceType` stuff and the `FilesMatch` and that will remove the restriction on images.  Wouldn't hurt to comment those lines out and restart the daemon and see if it fixes it.  If it causes any problems you can take the hash marks out and everything is back to normal.

Comment: Thanks for the highlights, @AbsoluteƵERØ, I should have done some of that myself for readability.

Comment: I didn't know about it until someone did it to one of my first posts. Thought I would pass on the favor.

Comment: Yeah, I did it to something else I posted and totally spaced here.  Nice to have someone take the time to help make your answer more readable for others.